# Google Maps Javascript API not loading correctly on Chromium based browsers

Tags: google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, chromium, jxbrowser

I am trying their Simple Map example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple), if I refresh the page a few times(the html page in the example saved locally) it just stops loading, the circle icon in Chrome rotates very slowly, and it takes 30sec-1min until it finally loads. Even if I close the tab and open it again, or load multiple tabs, it won't load. This doesn't happen on other browsers like Firefox, but I need to load the map in JxBrowser which is Chromium based and the same thing happen. I did use the api key, and there are no errors in the console. What could cause this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like an issue with the browser. Running it on the latest version of Chrome, it works perfectly fine, even after multiple refreshes. Maybe try the sample provided by JxBrowser instead: http://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/samples#TOC-Google-Maps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try the sample provided by JxBrowser, still the same problem. Do they perhaps have a limit of refreshes/minute or something? My application is using multiple browser windows, and that's why this is important, when I open a new window sometimes it does that, but other times I open lots of windows and it works fine...